# How to write the Tcl nested string rule in ANTLR?

Tags: escaping, nested, antlr, bnf

A Tcl nested String can be something like this:

```
{abc {xyz foo {hello world}}}
```

The braces above are used to enclose the content of string, they are not part of the string(Similar to double quotes). And they can be escaped using `"\{"` and `"\}"` to change string `"foo"` to `"foo{}"`:

```
{abc {xyz foo\{\} {hello world}}}
```

I have a working lexical rule for the one without the brace escaping:

```
NestedBraces
  :  '{' ( ~('{'|'}') | NestedBraces)* '}'
  ;
```

I am trying to find a way to add the escaping part while keeping the nested syntax, and haven't succeeded so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
NestedBraces
 : '{' (~('{' | '}' | '\\') | '\\' ('{' | '}') | NestedBraces)* '}'
 ;
```

In the inner loop, you match:

```
~('{' | '}' | '\\')   // anything other than a '{', '}' and '\'
|                     // OR
'\\' ('{' | '}')      // an escaped '{' or '}' 
|                     // OR
NestedBraces          // recursive call: '{' ... '}'
```

And if you want to strip the un-escaped braces from the tokens in one go, do something like this:

```
NestedBraces
 : Helper {setText($text.replaceAll("\\\\(.)|[{}]", "$1"));}
 ;

fragment Helper
 : '{' (~('{' | '}' | '\\') | '\\' ('{' | '}') | Helper)* '}'
 ;
```

which will create a token with inner text `"abc xyz foo{ hello world"` for the input `"{abc {xyz foo\{ {hello world}}}"`. Note that you need a helper rule: you can't do the replacement *and* also the recursive call in one rule.

Comment: Thanks. The syntax I used was very similar: {code}\nNestedBraces
 : '{'(EscapeBraces | ~('{'|'}') | NestedBraces)* '}';{code}

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, Bart.

Not able to type the code properly in comments section, so I am pasting my code here:

```
NestedBraces
:   '{'(EscapeBraces | ~('{'|'}') | NestedBraces)* '}';
fragment
EscapeBraces
:   '\\' 
    (
    '{' 
    | '}' 
    )
;
```